# Cant get createSlider from @typeform/embed to work in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typeform

I am trying to get @typeform/embed to work in React. I want to see them all before deciding which one is best for the case where I want to use it.

All types are imported and css is imported:

```
import { createPopover, createPopup, createSidetab, createSlider, createWidget } from '@typeform/embed'
import '@typeform/embed/build/css/widget.css';
import '@typeform/embed/build/css/popup.css';
import '@typeform/embed/build/css/popover.css';
import '@typeform/embed/build/css/sidetab.css';
import '@typeform/embed/build/css/slider.css';
```

In my code I have a dropdown menu to select the form I want to use. that value will be set with useState.
createWidget, createSidetab and createPopover are all working without problems

```
createWidget(formSelect, {container: document.querySelector('.formDiv') })
createSidetab(formSelect);
createPopover(formSelect);
```

However createPopup and createSlider arent showing up. Does anyone know how to let them show up?

```
createPopup(formSelect, {width: 500, height: 250})
createSlider(formSelect, {container: document.querySelector('.slideDiv')});
```

Maybe I use the wrong options, I don't know, can't get those working, while the other 3 are working absolutely fine!

**UPDATE: got createPopup to working using the 'open: "load"' option

Hope anyone can help me, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `createPopup` it creates the popup instance but it is up to you to open it.

You can open it based on a user action, eg. button click:

```
const open = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  createPopup(formSelect, { width: 500, height: 250 }).open();
};

return <button onClick={open}>click to open popup</button>;
```

Or you can open it automatically as you did with [custom launch options](https://developer.typeform.com/embed/configuration/#custom-launch-options): `{ open: "load" }`.

You should be able to use both approaches for `createSlider` too.

I have just discovered custom launch options (eg. `{ open: "load" }`) is broken for embed types other than popup. We are releasing [a fix for the embed library](https://github.com/Typeform/embed/pull/216) to resolve this. Please install latest version of the `@typeform/embed` lib (>= 1.1.4).

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working perfectly now!! Other quick question: do you maybe know anything of @typeform/api-client? I am dealing with a CORS policy issue

Comment: Other quick question, is there a way to read the answers given in the typeform, to do some things with those answers?

Comment: You could use [Responses API](https://developer.typeform.com/responses/) to retrieve the answers in `onSubmit` method.
However I think @typeform/api-client is supposed to be used server-side to avoid that CORS issue. You should create an endpoint that will fetch those data for you (and to keep [your token](https://developer.typeform.com/get-started/personal-access-token/) secret).